# Angular and Jasmine Test firebase auth with google provider cannot read property

Tags: angular, unit-testing, firebase-authentication, jasmine, ng-mocks

I'm starting with unit testing and it's hard to test a method that login using firebase auth. I've tried it in many ways and tested it in several means as you can see in the code comments and in most cases it always returns:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'GoogleAuthProvider' of undefined`

I used the **ng-mocks** library to mock **AngularFireAuth**.

the project can be seen in this branch of the project on **[github branch](https://github.com/miguelsmuller/angular-11-crud/tree/feature/unit-teste)**

this is the **method** i want to test:

```
login(): Observable<IUser> {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    const responseAuth = from(this.fireAuthService.signInWithPopup(provider)).pipe(
      map((fireUser) => {
        const objUser: IUser = {
          uid: fireUser.user?.uid!,
          name: fireUser.user?.displayName!,
          email: fireUser.user?.email!,
          emailVerified: fireUser.user?.emailVerified!,
          photoURL: fireUser.user?.photoURL!,
          provider: fireUser.user?.providerId!,
        };
        return objUser;
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        throw new Error('error in the logout process');
      })
    );

    return responseAuth;
  }
```

this is the **test**.

```
it('should executed login method with success', fakeAsync(() => {
    const googleSignInMethod = spyOn(fireAuthService, 'signInWithPopup');

    service.login().subscribe((data) => {
      expect(googleSignInMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    // const googleSignInMethod = spyOn(fireAuthService, 'signInWithPopup').and.callThrough();
    // service.login().subscribe((data) => {});
    // expect(googleSignInMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();

    // service.login().subscribe((data) => {
    //   let spy = spyOn(fireAuthService, 'signInWithPopup');
    // expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(provider);
    //   expect(spyOn(fireAuthService, 'signInWithPopup')).toBeTruthy();
    // });
    // spy = spyOn(service, 'isAuthenticated').and.returnValue(false); (3)
    // expect(component.needsLogin()).toBeTruthy();
    // expect(service.isAuthenticated).toHaveBeenCalled(); (4)
  }));
```

Comment: Might you add a code sample how you mock `AngularFireAuth`?

Comment: `MockProvider(AuthService)` i am using ng-moks https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks

Comment: Cannot find a test with `MockProvider(AuthService)` on https://github.com/miguelsmuller/angular-11-crud/tree/feature/unit-teste. Might you add it there?

Comment: https://github.com/miguelsmuller/angular-11-crud/blob/feature/unit-teste/src/app/core/services/auth.service.spec.ts#L16
Sorry about that. I hadn't pushed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the test is that in testing environment `new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();` fails due to 0 existing apps.

There are 2 solutions how to fix it:

1. Provide a testing app
2. Avoid usage of `new` in the method and make the dependency to be injected.

The 2nd way is the preferred one:

```js
export const FIREBASE_AUTH_PROVIDER = new InjectionToken('FIREBASE_AUTH_PROVIDER', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(),
});

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private fireAuthService: AngularFireAuth,
    @Inject(FIREBASE_AUTH_PROVIDER) private readonly fireAuthProvider: firebase.auth.AuthProvider,
  ) {}

  login(): Observable<IUser> {
    const responseAuth = from(this.fireAuthService.signInWithPopup(this.fireAuthProvider)).pipe(
// .....
```

Then in the test the dependency can be easily replaced with a mock:

```js
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        MockProvider(AngularFireAuth),
        MockProvider(FIREBASE_AUTH_PROVIDER, {}),
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    service = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
    fireAuthService = TestBed.inject(AngularFireAuth);
  });

  it('should executed login method with success', fakeAsync(() => {
    const googleSignInMethod = spyOn(fireAuthService, 'signInWithPopup');
    googleSignInMethod.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({
      credential: null,
      user: null,
    }));

    service.login().subscribe((data) => {
      expect(googleSignInMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    // const googleSignInMethod = spyOn(fireAuthService, 'signInWithPopup').and.callThrough();
    // service.login().subscribe((data) => {});
    // expect(googleSignInMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();

    // service.login().subscribe((data) => {
    //   let spy = spyOn(fireAuthService, 'signInWithPopup');
    // expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(provider);
    //   expect(spyOn(fireAuthService, 'signInWithPopup')).toBeTruthy();
    // });
    // spy = spyOn(service, 'isAuthenticated').and.returnValue(false); (3)
    // expect(component.needsLogin()).toBeTruthy();
    // expect(service.isAuthenticated).toHaveBeenCalled(); (4)
  }));
```

Comment: OK. understand. I think it's it.
More then I ask you? From your experience, is this the best solution I have for my code? Why was i thinking, if in the future, i need to enter another provider like facebook or github?

Comment: yep. it is quite good. For facebook, you could easily provide `AuthService` as `useClass: AuthFacebookService` with its own `login` method, and the transition should be barely noticeable.